# How to ask if a connection/relationship exists between two things

Tags: grammar, syntax, phrase-requests

I would like to ask if there is a connection or relationship between two different parts.

For example, would this be an appropriate way of asking "Is there any connection between the two compilations/volumes?"

> 2つの編に何か関係はありますか？

I'm not certain if I'm missing anything required when discussing the connection/relationship (for example の間, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 2つの～(の間)に何か関係はありますか is a perfectly natural sentence. の間 is typically optional, but dropping it may make the sentence ambiguous depending on the context:

> 2人に何か関係はありますか?
>
> 1. Are the two people related to each other?
> 2. Are the two people related to (the problem / it / him / etc)?

Adding の間 makes the sentence refer only to the connection *between* the two.

Also note that 編 does not work as a standalone noun except in limited stiff contexts. Instead, you may want to use 作品, 本, シリーズ, etc.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you, corrected. Feel free to correct my bad English.